# Fresh flutter demo app: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sf.fbc" on moto e20

Tags: android, flutter, libc, motorola

I created a new Flutter project (Flutter Demo) and used my moto e20 for debugging. I did not make any modifications to the example code.

In debug console i get the following errors.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on moto e20 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56915/W6uTaIvADtc=/ws
Syncing files to device moto e20...
I/gralloc4( 9954): register: id=1b1000000ab
E/libc    ( 9954): Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sf.fbc"
E/libc    ( 9954): Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.gpu.fbc"
E/libc    ( 9954): Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.vsp.fbc"
I/gralloc4( 9954): register: id=1b1000000ac
I/gralloc4( 9954): register: id=1b1000000ad
```

---

My toolchain is:

- Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2251])
- Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
- Android Studio (version 2021.3)

---

I could not find anything helpful by searching for "access denied property" and the "persist.vendor.x" properties.

What would be the starting point to track this error down?

Any links or keywords, where to look, would already help.